# Qt UI slow to respond even after using threads

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside

I am trying to build an image/video processing application using PySide and have been trying to keep the UI responsive while the image processing takes place. However, despite using a thread the UI is still slow to respond to input. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong would be very helpful.

```
class Communicate(QObject):
    sendPixmap = Signal(QPixmap)
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

class UpdateThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.signals = Communicate()
        self.signals.sendPixmap.connect(parent.receiveFrame)

    def run(self):
        print("[INFO] updateFrame called")
        while window.threadFlag:
            print("Processing")
            start = time.time()
            qtImg = videoController.nextQtFrame()
            pixmap = QPixmap(qtImg)
            self.signals.sendPixmap.emit(pixmap.scaled(self.parent.ui.imgDisplayLabel.size(),
                                                    Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                                                    Qt.SmoothTransformation))
            end = time.time()
            print("Time taken: ", end - start)
        print("[INFO] update frame finished")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initialising Main Window")
        start = time.time()
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.threadFlag = True
        self.thread = UpdateThread(self)
        self.thread.start()
        end = time.time()
        print("Time taken: ",end - start)

    @Slot(QPixmap)
    def receiveFrame(self, pixmap):
        print("Receiving and displaying frame")
        start = time.time()
        print("[INFO] receiveFrame Slot invoked!")
        self.ui.imgDisplayLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
        end = time.time()
        print("Time taken: ",end - start)


    def closeEvent(self, event:QCloseEvent):
        # Closing the video capture thread
        videoController.threadFlag =False
        self.threadFlag = False
        self.thread.wait()
        super(MainWindow, self).closeEvent(event)
        app.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)
    videoController = VideoController()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do not use QPixmap in a secondary thread instead you must use QImage.

Comment: On the other hand, using a secondary thread does not serve to improve speed but does not block other elements. If you want faster then you should make your processing more efficient

Comment: It blocks my elements for a few milliseconds. I tried using QImage but to no avail.